# Change manually placeholder text in input "postalCode" in Stripe from "ZIP" or "Postal Code" to "ZIP/Postal"

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments, nuxt.js, placeholder, stripe-payments-js

I'm using "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.9.0" in nuxt.js app...and must change text in placeholder `<input class="InputElement is-empty Input Input--empty" autocomplete="postal-code" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" type="text" name="postal" data-elements-stable-field-name="postalCode" inputmode="numeric" aria-label="ZIP" placeholder="ZIP" aria-invalid="false" value="">` from "ZIP" to "ZIP/Postal" according my current task). But official DOC did not help me with it and STRIPE-support did not help me also...any ideas how can I change placeholder?) and also in future I need to change this text by other languages )

Comment: we can create personal custom `<input v-model.trim="zipPostal" @input="onInputZipPostal()" placeholder="my placeholder"/>` and add new data for "address_zip" field in stripe object when we send stripeTokent: `stripe.createToken(this.card, { address_zip: this.zipPostal }).then(function (result) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the all-in-one `card` element, you can place the individual `cardNumber`, `cardExpiry` and `cardCvc` elements to the your own postal input element, of which you can customize the label as you want.

Remember to include the value of postalCode that you collected from your own postal code input element when [confirming](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment#confirm_payment_intent-options-confirmParams-payment_method_data-billing_details) the payment.

See https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/other_element